# Changing data type in oracle without deleting the data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
Product Version Oracle 10g
```

I have a table in oracle with some data in it. There is a column which of type Number(10,0). Now i want to change it to Number(10,2) to allow decimals. But to change, oracle is not allowing without deleting the existing data.
I know i can take the data backup -> delete data -> change type -> insert data back.
But the problem is there is an auto insert column which gets value from a sequence.
So when i insert it back those id will change....I am not sure that if anyone is using that id as a key to get the data. So how can i change it without altering the ids..

Please help..

Comment: probably you want number(12,2). For example, number(7,2) is a number that has 5 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: you may disable the triggers. "Alter trigger x disable".

Comment: @FlorinGhita i need (12,2) ...thnks for pointing it out...will try with disabling the trigger -> insert data -> enable trigger

Comment: Do you still get the ORA-01440 using `number(12,2)`? I don't in 11g, but may depend on what data is present I suppose.

Comment: @AlexPoole No...Number(12,2) is working without any issue....when you decrease it then only that error is coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want number(12,2) to keep precision. 
For example, number(7,2) is a number that has 5 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.

Alternately, you may disable the trigger / do the work / enable the trigger.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the new NUMBER(12,2) column, but with a different name.
2. Update the new column, converting all the values from the old column.
3. Drop the old column.
4. Rename the new column with the desired name.